# Problem with Automapper 8.0 in a .NET WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, automapper

I have just upgraded Automapper in my WCF Service project to the newest version 8.0.0. I get following error when calling the service via WCF Test client:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Mapper already initialized. You must call Initialize once per application domain/process.'

With the old Automapper version 6.0.2 it's working and no exception is thrown. I initialzed the Mapper with a seperate Service Behaviour class.

Service Class **EdiPartners.cs**:

```
[AutomapServiceBehavior]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, InstanceContextMode = 
InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class EdiPartners : IPartners
{
    [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionObject))]
    public Supplier GetPartnerData(string SupplierNumber)
    {
       // Code
    }
}
```

Service Behaviour Class **AutomapServiceBehavior**:

```
    public sealed class AutomapServiceBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
    {
    #region IServiceBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, 
    ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
    Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection 
    bindingParameters)
    {
        AutomapBootstrap.InitializeMap();
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Static Automapper Initializing Class **AutomapBootstrap**:

```
   public class AutomapBootstrap
{
    public static void InitializeMap()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<Supplier, IEdiPartnerData>();
            config.CreateMap<IEdiPartnerData, Supplier>();
            config.CreateMap<IEdiPartner, EdiPartner>();

        });
    }
}
```

Maybe you guys can help me. I don't understand why it is working with the old but not with the new version. Is there a better way for initializing Automapper in a WCF Service?

Thx in advance,
Sandro

Comment: By the way, `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` makes no sense when `InstanceContextMode = 
InstanceContextMode.PerCall`.  It's not possible to share the server

Comment: Not sure it is related to your issue, but you could change your redundant Supplier-IEdiPartnerData mappings (back and forth) and instead use `config.CreateMap<Supplier, IEdiPartnerData>().ReverseMap()`.

Comment: @MickyD see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and#Instance%20mode%20=%20per%20Call%20and%20Concurrency%20=%20Multiple

Comment: @Edword thx, did not know this method

Comment: Because the old version didn't throw. But your code was broken nevertheless.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu and what exactly is broken in my code? Can you help with?

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure that codeproject proves anything.  A gap of 2 seconds between calls is zero evidence for concurrency. The _"different threads"_ is also just an indication of random thread assignment from the thread pool. Like I said, it's a pointless configuration for the mode you are in.  _[Programming WCF Services: Mastering WCF and the Azure AppFabric Service Bus](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Mastering-AppFabric/dp/0596805489)_

Comment: I need a solution what to adjust in my code, no more and no less!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to implement a custom service host factory class:

```
public class EdiPartnersFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
   protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   {
    // Initialize Automapper
    AutomapBootstrap.InitializeMap();

    var host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

    return host;
    }
}
```

And I changed the web.config for the service contract and the binding:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Company.Sap.EdiPartners"
             behaviorConfiguration="MEXServiceTypeBehavior">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="Company.Sap.IPartners" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MEXServiceTypeBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Change the .svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Company.Sap.EdiPartners" Factory="Company.Sap.EdiPartnersFactory" CodeBehind="EdiPartners.svc.cs" %>
```

So no use of a service binding in the service class (looks much more cleaner):

```
public class EdiPartners : IPartners
{
    [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionObject))]
    public Supplier GetPartnerData(string SupplierNumber)
    {
       // Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention who suggested it

Answer (score 2):

Since your service is `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` a new instance will be created per call.  In addition, because you have decorated your service with `[AutomapServiceBehavior]` it is going to initialise not once per AppDomain (like the error says) but *per instance*.

So change your code to:

```
public sealed class AutomapServiceBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    static bool _initialised;

#region IServiceBehavior Members
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        if (_initialised)  // already init'd per this AppDomain
            return;

        AutomapBootstrap.InitializeMap();
        _initialised = true;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
#endregion
}
```

### Useful Service Behaviours or Custom Service Host?

By the way, `AutomapServiceBehavior` is probably not a good example of writing service behaviours because if you intend to decorate multiple services with it (possibly with different mappings) in the same assembly it won't work.  AutoMapper likes to be **initialised** only **once** at **application startup** so if it were going to be initialised anywhere I would put it in a custom `ServiceHost` and do away with the behaviour.

Comment: thx for the answer you saved my day. I've implemented your suggestion with a service host factory. I will post it seperatly.

Comment: I am really confused here. If we check _initialised as you suggested, then the initialization will happen only once per Application domain since the static _initialised is an application state variable. So why won't the Automapper work properly? Also if I want to use the Custom Service Host as you suggested like the answer Sandro has posted, will I need to create a seperate Factory for each service class?

Comment: @Karamafrooz AutoMapper will work correctly if it is initialsed exactly once per AppDomain.  Otherwise you will encounter _"Mapper already initialized. You must call Initialize once per application domain/process"_